# Fatal when I create database

Tags: django, database, postgresql, digital-ocean

I want to automatically install postgres database using Fabric.
To do this, read this tutorial:https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn

I wrote the code:

```
def fresh_database():
     "" "
     install database
     "" "
     local ('pip install -r Requirements/prod.txt')
     local ('sudo apt-get install python-dev libpq-dev')
     local ('sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib)
     local ('sudo su - postgres')
     local ('createdb mydb')
     local ('createuser -P')

     print (green ('OK.'))
```

But when I create database I get the error: createdb: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
sudo('psql -U postgres -c "CREATE DATABASE mydb WITH OWNER username")
```

It should work.